# What would be output of following program in c++?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std; 
void test(int *s){
  s++;
  *s=3;
}
int main(){
  int s=0;
  test(&s);
  cout<<s;
  return 0;
}
```

The output I am getting **000**. I was expecting only 0. But I am getting zeros equal to value assigned to s in test function. I am not able to understand why is it giving this output?

Edited.

Comment: Your program exhibits *undefined behavior*, because `s++` does not point to a valid location in memory.

Comment: Won't compile, so any output is moot.

Comment: See [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

Comment: @NeilButterworth It is compiling and output is what I have written in question.

Comment: @s.singh It cannot possibly compile. You have not included the header files needed for declarations of things like `cout` and the `<<` operator.

Comment: Your compiler really compiled this without complaining? `int main{`

Comment: @s.singh Your code [definitely doesn't compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3a2887c52ebe98a)! Stop wasting everybody's time with bogus code but post a [MCVE] please.

Comment: Please make a [mcve] of the code you are actually compiling and running. I think we can agree that the code in the current question is something else. Then we can look for the explanation of "000" instead of "0". Feel free to fix the UB, but (in fairness towards those who already answered) specifically say so in your edit, please.

Comment: @s.singh [Still no repro](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b0c13401304186d7). I'd say what your output shows is because of _undefined behavior_. Everything can happen.

Answer (score 3):

*Undefined behaviour is undefined.* When called like in your `main`, `test` writes through an invalid pointer, so anything can happen.

Answer (score 3):

Your program has undefined behavior.

The line

```
s++;
```

increments the pointer, not the value of the object the pointer points to.

and then the line

```
*s=3;
```

modified the value at of the new location the pointer points to. That is accessing memory that you are not supposed to access.

Answer (score 2):

You passed &s in test function argument so the *s is the actual value but when you incremented s the pointer went to an undefined location and hence the output could be anything. remove the line s++ and you will get 3 as answer.

Comment: I know this much that after removing s++, I will get 3 as output. But I am asking why am i getting 3 '0' instead of one. Try to understand the question.